# Convert semver version string (10.2.3) to long

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

Here's a fun task...

Given a lot of version strings - assuming they are more or less semantic version [semantic version](http://semver.org/) numbers like 1.2.3 - what's a way to convert that to a long (in Java), so that it holds that "1.2.34" is less than "12.3.0"?

Here's what I have so far

```
public static Long toLong(String version) {
    if (version == null || version.isEmpty()) {
        return 0L;
    }
    String[] parts = version.split("[^0-9]");
    long number = 0L;
    long factor = 1;
    for (int b = parts.length - 1; b >= 0; b--) { 
        try {
            Long l = Long.parseLong(parts[b]);
            number += l * factor;
            factor = factor * 100;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            // silently ignored
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

It assumes no position in the string has more than two digits (so 1.2.3.4567) will not work properly, but I can live with that. But I'd like to have something faster.

Comment: Why a `long`? Why not a class with members for major, minor and patch (and other parts of a semver version)?

Comment: Good question. Mainly optimisation, simplification, and interoperability. The long values go into other (non-java) systems and we wanted something that is simple and super fast to compare.

Comment: Multiply major by 100, minor by 10, sum the three numbers. You'll rarely find three digit version files and when you do, they are likely to be patch numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a similar transformation within `String`:

```
// add "." to format the major version
("." + versionString).
    // replace each "." with "a00"
    replaceAll("\\.", "a00").
    // keep 2 digits, remove "a" and extra leading "0"
    replaceAll("a0+([0-9]{2})", "$1");
```

This method can be easily adopted for different number of significant digits and/or different formats of the input string. Performance is ~2.4x slower than that of your toLong method (2.5 s to format 1M version strings). If performance is more important than simplicity of code, this is about 5.5x faster (0.2 s for 1M strings), than your toLong method:

```
public static Long toLong2(String versionString)
{  
  if (versionString == null || versionString.isEmpty() )
  {  
    return 0L;
  } // end if empty
  char[] C = versionString.toCharArray();
  int i, i1 = 0, i2 = C.length;
  Long l, number = 0L, factor = 1L;
  try
  {
    for (i = C.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {  
      if (C[i] == '.')
      {  
        i1 = i + 1; 
        l = Long.parseLong(versionString.substring(i1, i2) ); 
        i2 = i; 
        number += l * factor;
        factor = factor * 100L;
      } // end if '.'
    } // end for i
    l = Long.parseLong(versionString.substring(0, i2) ); 
    number += l * factor;
    }  
  catch (NumberFormatException e) 
  {  
    // silently ignored
  } // end try
  return number;
} // end method toLong2
```